# What is the use of List<NameValuePair> or ArrayList<NameValuePair>

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to know about What is the use of `List<NameValuePair>` or `ArrayList<NameValuePair>` in android? Specially when we are using web services using `AsyncTask<...>`

Answer (score 60, accepted):

NameValuePair is a special `<Key, Value>` pair which is used to represent parameters in http request, i.e. `www.example.com?key=value`.

NameValuePair is an interface and is defined in apache http client, which is widely used in java to handle http operations. A `List<NameValuePair>` is just a list of `<key, value>` pairs, and will be used as params in http post request.

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost();
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key", "value"));
request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

httpClient.execute(request);
```

Comment: code line 3 should be  params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key", "value")); missing )

Comment: can I use it in other thing than HTTP request ?

Answer (score 12):

Some useful stuff for you.

`List` is an interface and `ArrayList` is an implementation of the `List` interface.

`List`: `List` is an interface in collection framework. several classes like `ArrayList`, `LinkedList` implement this interface. `List` is an ordered collection , so the position of an object does matter.

`ArrayList`: An `ArrayList` is a class which can grow at runtime. you can store java objects in an `ArrayList` and also add new objects at run time.

You will use `ArrayList` when you don't have to add or remove objects frequently from it. Because when you remove an object, all other objects need to be re-positioned inside the `ArrayList`, if you have this kind of situation, try using `LinkedList` instead.

You can find out more information from [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/02/difference-between-linkedlist-vs.html).

Answer (score 10):

`List<NameValuePair>` or `ArrayList<NameValuePair>` are used to send values from android app to server.

```
@Override
    protected Header[] doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(params[1]);

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ssn", params[0]));
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair,
                    "UTF-8"));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
            allHeaders = httpResponse.getAllHeaders();

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();

        }
        return allHeaders;
    }
```

In the code above, I'm passing an attribute `ssn` to server using `ArrayList<NameValuePair>`.

Answer (score 0):

Used this code for Upload Datas from android app to server side..

```
  // image file *********************************
 // here send all the sqlite database datas to local sever via HttpPost("url"); 

ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("job_id","001"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("picture_path",picturejson.toString()));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date_time",datetime_str));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("location",gpslocation_str));
        try{

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://Sample/iphone/getinput");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        //HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        //is = entity.getContent();
        //HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
             response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
                        String sResponse;
                        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

                        while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            s = s.append(sResponse);
                        }
                    System.out.println("Response: ");
                    Log.v("hari", "Response : ");
        }catch(Exception e){
        //Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected String  doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            try
            {
                List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", edName));
            param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", edEmail));
            param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",  edPassword));
            param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobile", edMobile));


            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            InputStream is = httpEntity.getContent();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            String  json = sb.toString();
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(json);
            msg= jObj.getString("message");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

            Log.e("error", "Network problem");
        }
        return msg;

    }
}
```