# How to create dynamic url with multiple parameters?

Tags: android, url, uri

I want to create url with dynamic parameters ?

```
new Uri.Builder()
.scheme("http")
.authority("foo.com")
.path("someservlet")
.appendQueryParameter("param1", foo)
.appendQueryParameter("param2", bar)
.build();
```

the above Uri class is member of android.net

I have unknown number of params , How can I create dynamic url when I don't know the number of parameters ?

Comment: you already answered your question: .appendQueryParameter

Comment: dude in My answer two parameters are appended , I have multiple  parameters for append and I don't know the numbers of parameter

Comment: buddy, I know the parameters, but number of parameters is dynamic (not fixed)

Comment: so what? iterate over them and call appendQueryParameter... its so easy, whats the problem?

Comment: can you please give me solution by code? I have parameters in ArrayListList<NameValuePair> now give me solution bro

Comment: b = new Uri.Builder(); foreach(key in something) {b.appendQueryParameter(key, value); }

Comment: Uri b = new Uri.Builder(); not working , giving compile time error, message is "Change type of 'b' to 'Builder'  "   and also we cant append parameters after build the uri, we must specify that at the time of building uri

Comment: whem you use new Uri.Builder() so b should be declared as Uri.Builder and nor Uri, then call appendQueryParameter x times and finally call build to get the Uri, that is how builders work

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52658/discussion-between-jayesh-and-pskink)

Answer (score 2):

Given that the nameValuePairs are set before you can first declare the URIBuilder and then add all parameters with their keys in iterative manner through the List.

```
Uri uri;
Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
    builder.scheme("http")
    .encodedAuthority("foo.com")
    .appendEncodedPath("someservlet");

    for (NameValuePair l : nameValuePairs)
    {
        builder.appendQueryParameter(l.getName(), l.getValue());
    }

    uri = builder.build();
```

Finally you can get the Uri object from the builder object.

For reference how to build a List of NameValuePair please refer to this post:
[What is the use of List<NameValuePair> or ArrayList<NameValuePair>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607589/what-is-the-use-of-listnamevaluepair-or-arraylistnamevaluepair)