# What is new value pair in Android?

Tags: java, android

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://www.tree.com/action.php?fun=login");
List<NameValuePairs> Params= new ArrayList<NameValuePairs>();
Params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",username));
Post.setEntity(UrlEncodedFormEntity(Params));
```

I am unable to understand the concept of using `new BasicNameValuePair("username",username)`. Does it relate to the `ArrayList` index? What is the advantage of using it?

Comment: i couldn't find any references for this method eather

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/message/BasicNameValuePair.html

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17609232/4224337

Comment: does it mean the key  act as an index of array list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NameValuePairs is like associative array. The operations are not made by integer indexes, they are made by Strings.
They look something like this

```
"One"->"Value1"
"Two"->"Value2"
"Three"->"Value3"
```