# Calling web service api from android but parameter missing error

Tags: c#, android, asp.net

I am trying to call web service api from android app, code shown below:

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("check", "chk"));
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(HTTP_CHECK);
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
httpClient.execute(post);
HttpResponse httpres = httpClient.execute(post);
```

This is my web service API on asp.net

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld2(String check)
    {
        return "SuccessCheck";
    }
```

Host Server is Godaddy.
The above method worked previously. But now it gives the error on an app -

> System.InvalidOperationException:Missing Parameter:check.

How it says that parameter is missing. The parameter is passed as namevaluepair. I don't know what the problem is? However, it works perfectly on localhost.

Service methods which do not have any parameters work well on a server as well as on local host.
Now when I change the android code as below

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(HTTP_CHECK + "?check=chk");
httpClient.execute(post);
HttpResponse httpres = httpClient.execute(post);
```

Now it works well on a server as well as host. As I am passing the parameter with URL as given above and not using a name-value pair.

What is the problem in the first scenario and why it suddenly changed?
Please help.

Comment: in your first android code you create the "ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePair" but never use it anywhere when doing the actual Http calls.

Comment: here you can see how it's used: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607589/what-is-the-use-of-listnamevaluepair-or-arraylistnamevaluepair

Comment: Thanks for your comments. But I have used it. Result is not yet working. Its very strange.

Comment: then please update your question with the real code, cause in your snippet it's still missing

Answer (score 1):

In the first scenario you are not using `nameValuePair` anywhere.

Add this bit:

`post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));` before you call `httpClient.execute(post);`

Comment: No this is not the answer as I have used it. I only forgot to mention it on my question however I have used it in my origianl source. Please help